# Cross Platform Multiplayer Game(app)

Tags: android, ios, cross-platform, game-center, multiplayer

As you all know,for Multiplayer game apps, iOS provides Game Center and Google's Game Center is under development however Private game centers like GREE and MOBGAGE can do this job well.

Interestingly, games like "Words with friends" and "Fun Run" wants you to just logs in with facebook id and then the game manages online match-making, multiplayer games etc.

Please hint, if facebook can be used as a Universal Game Center as every OS have its accessibility.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has released [Play Game Services](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/games.html). It works on iOS, Android and Web, it also has multiplayer support and stores Achievements and Leaderboards for your game.

As far as I know, Facebook can be used as an authorization platform, but you still need your own server/backend to keep track of player data, achievements, leaderboards, etc.

Comment: Thanks Dannie. I will try it for sure.